# Как проверить номер на наличие whatsapp python?

Tags: python, whatsapp

Хочу узнать, зарегистрирован ли номер на **whatsapp** через python, но не могу понять, как можно такое реализовать без API, т.к оно платно. Дается, конечно, на тест 3 дня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри, я делал через селениум, но помню насколько код работоспособен, но там буквально минимальные изменения могут поправить его)

P.S Я не профессионал, не судите код строго, это вообще мой первый Python проект. Делал собирая по кусочкам гайды и документации к библиотекам, если кто-то готов поправить, сделать его более работоспособным и скинуть сюда буду очень рад. Так же можем развивать эту идею вместе)

**Main.py**

```
# Импорт библиотек
import random  # Рандом
import time  # Работа с временем
import selenium.common.exceptions


from messages import message_list
from messages import read_mess_file
from messages import change_message_list
from import_numbers_from_excel import whatsapp_urls
from import_numbers_from_excel import read_numbers_from_excel
from selenium import webdriver  # Библиотека браузера и действий с ним
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  # Для интеграции нужного эллемента
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  # Клавиатура и работа с ней
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  # Для поиска элемента
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # Задержка загрузки страницы

path = 'database.xlsx'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()


def whatsapp_base():
    read_numbers_from_excel(path)


def scan_qr(i, whatsapp_url):
    if i == 0:
        print("Сканируй QR-code в браузере")
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get(whatsapp_url)
    else:
        driver.get(whatsapp_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)


def browse_work():
    read_mess_file()
    change_message_list()
    whatsapp_base()
    length = len(whatsapp_urls) - 1
    for i in range(length):
        whatsapp_url = whatsapp_urls[i]
        try:
            scan_qr(i, whatsapp_url)
            incorrect_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/span[2]'
                                                            '/div[1]/span/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div')
            incorrect_number.click()
            print('Сообщение контату -', whatsapp_url, 'не доставлено')
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            input_msg = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]')))
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            for x in range(len(message_list)):
                input_msg.send_keys(message_list[x] + Keys.ENTER)
                rand = random.randint(5, 10)
                time.sleep(rand)
            print('Контату -', whatsapp_url, 'доставлены сообщения')


browse_work()
```

**Messages.py**
# Messages work(add, remove, see, change)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

message_list = []
path = 'messages.xlsx'


def add_message(how):
    """Добавление элемента(ов) из массива"""
    global message_list
    for i in range(how):
        print('Введите сообщение которое хотите добавить:')
        message = input()
        message_list.append(message)


def change_message(how):
    """Изменение элемента(ов) из массива"""
    global message_list
    for a in range(how):
        print('Какое сообщение следует изменить:')
        change = int(input())
        print('Введите сообщение на которое следует поменять:')
        change_mess = input()
        message_list[change] = change_mess


def del_message(how):
    """Удаление элемента(ов) из массива"""
    global message_list
    for x in range(how):
        print('Какие сообщения хотите удалить?')
        delete = int(input())
        del message_list[delete]


def see_messages():
    """Вощваращает построчно все элементы массива message_list"""
    global message_list
    for z in range(len(message_list)):
        print(message_list[z])


def read_mess_file():
    """Читает сообщения из excel файла и добавляет их в массив"""
    global message_list
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=path)
    active_file = workbook.active
    max_row = active_file.max_row
    for row in range(1, max_row):
        message = active_file[row][0].value
        message_list.append(message)


def change_message_list():
    """Обрабатывает запроос пользователя и позволяет ему при помощи команд
    изменять, добавлять, удалять и просматривать списки соощений.
    Парамтры для изменения:
    add,a - Добавление элемента(ов) в список
    del,d - Удаление элемента(ов) из списка
    see,s - Возвращает все элементы массива
    change, c - Замена элемента(ов) массива
    exit, e - выход из программы изменения"""
    changes = True
    while changes:
        answer = input('\nКоманды для работы с сообщениями\nadd - Добавить сообщение\ndel - Удалить сообщение\n'
                       'see - посмотреть список сообщений\nchange - Изменить сообщение\n'
                       'exit - выйти из редактирования списка\n')
        if answer == 'add' or answer == 'a':
            print('Сколько?')
            count_add = int(input())
            add_message(count_add)
        elif answer == 'del' or answer == 'd':
            print('Сколько?')
            how_del = int(input())
            del_message(how_del)
        elif answer == 'see' or answer == 's':
            see_messages()
        elif answer == 'change' or answer == 'c':
            print('Сколько?')
            how_change = int(input())
            change_message(how_change)
        elif answer == 'exit' or answer == 'e':
            changes = False
        else:
            print('\nКоманда не распознана, список команд:\nadd, a\ndel, d\nsee, s\nchange, c\nexit, e\n')
```

**ImportNumsFromExcel.py**
#Import numbers from excel to whatsapp urls

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

numbers_list = []
whatsapp_urls = []
count_numbers = 0


def read_workbook(path):
    """Читаем Excel файл с сообщеиями и формируем массив. Если
    номера в нём нет, то добавляем, если есть то выводим ошибку"""
    global numbers_list
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=path)
    active_file = workbook.active
    max_row = active_file.max_row + 1
    for row in range(1, max_row):
        if row >= 2:
            number = active_file[row][0].value
            if number in numbers_list:
                print('Номер:', number, 'уже есть в списке')
            else:
                numbers_list.append(number)


def import_dict_to_urls():
    """Используем массив для создания Whatsapp ссылок для рассылки"""
    for count in range(len(numbers_list)):
        number_for_url = numbers_list[count]
        whatsapp_url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + str(number_for_url)
        whatsapp_urls.append(whatsapp_url)


def print_urls():
    """Выводит все эллементы списка"""
    for i in range(len(whatsapp_urls)):
        print(whatsapp_urls[i])


def read_numbers_from_excel(path):
    """Открытие чтение и конвертирование номеров в список"""
    global whatsapp_urls
    read_workbook(path)
    import_dict_to_urls()
    return whatsapp_urls
```